# Is every inhabited planet within Federation space a member?

Tags: star-trek, federation

The UFP consists of approximately 150 member planets and most maps show the territory it covers to be about a quarter of the Milky Way.

Given that the Star Trek universe has no shortage of worlds inhabited by sentient races, and actual [mathematical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) estimating the number of intelligent races in the galaxy puts the upper bound in the millions, it seems that there are probably more than 150 planets inhabited by sentient races within Federation space.

Are there any known examples of planets within Federation space but are not members? Should the existence of these planets not make maps of the Federation a bit “Swiss-cheese”, in the sense that there will be what are essentially enclaves of other territory bound by it. Do these races have transit rights through Federation space (assume this would be a yes given the Federation’s position of relative openness and non-aggression).

Comment: I often wondered that myself. Not to mention cultured who were protected by the Prime Directive (i.e. not yet warp-capable) achieving warp capability years later and finding themselves in the middle of an established alien empire.

Comment: Disagree on the dupe. None of the answers in that question give cast iron examples, only assumptions and real-world analogies.

Comment: @Darren - My answer shows specific examples from a canon source; Rubicun III, for example; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rubicun_III

Comment: @valorum, Ah, you’re right, apologies. I missed that answer in my hasty scan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, there are plenty of neutral planets in Federation space.

A quick scan through this [amazing interactive map](http://www.startrekmap.com/ufpmain.html) shows that numerous examples of neutral planets can be found in Federation space. [Barzan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barzan), [Lyssaria](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lyssarian), and [Tarkalea](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkalea) are all examples I picked at random.

### Yes, Federation territory is "swiss cheese".

A lot of the maps I've seen lump most neutral planets into Federation territory, avoiding the "swiss cheese" look on a map but some cultures stake their claim on a large amount of space and the holes are unmistakable, especially on maps that show territory from a different perspective than the traditional top-down (space is 3 dimensional after all).

For example, according to this map, sliced "vertically" (credit to @Valorum), both the Klingon and Romulan Empires encroach Federation-controlled territory in a way that creates quite the dimple:

[image: vertical slice federation map]

You also have this map (thanks to @Valorum in the comments) that shows the Lysian Alliance, Satarran Empire, and others creating entire holes in Federation Space:

[image: federation map]

### Yes, non-Federation species can travel freely.

Well... mostly. Non-Federation civilizations are mostly left alone to govern themselves - travel included - unless there is a good defensive reason to restrict it. A [speed limit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Speed_limit) was enacted, for example, for safety reasons but it was never forced upon non-Federation members. And when the Dominion/Cardassians/Romulans/Klingons/whoever-the-Federation-is-at-war-with enter Federation space during wartime, you'd better believe a harsh response was appropriate (See [TNG: "The Defector"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Defector_(episode)), for example).

Comment: That's the map that I colourised for another question. A) You might like to credit me and b) It doesn't show Klingon space within Federation territory. It shows Klingon space *piercing* Federation territory.

Comment: @Valorum - Ah, I'll certainly give credit where due. I didn't realize you colorized it.  :)

Comment: You're still making an erroneous claim about Klingon and Romulan space being entirely within the borders of Federation space. That map represents a single 'slice' of space. From [a different angle](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e3/fb/fd/e3fbfd70799c276d318c1a952ea694bf.jpg) you can see that The Klingon Empire is huge and extends well beyond the borders of Federation space

Comment: Good answer, but are the three examples you given definitive within Federation space? I can’t see any mention of them in the Memory Alpha articles.

Comment: @Darren - I'm not sure how "difinitive" their locations are given the inconsistencies from map to map. I'm basing those location solely on the interactive map I linked to in the beginning of the question.